# In iOS 4.0, why does UIScrollView zoomToRect:animated: not trigger the scrollViewDidScroll or scrollViewDidZoom delegates while animating?

Tags: ios, ios4, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I need to closely monitor the scale of the scroll view so that I can update the content view's elements (a subview managing multiple *CALayers*) according to the scroll view's animated zoom.

On iOS 3.1, everything works as expected, I use *zoomToRect:animated:* and the *scrollViewDidScroll:* message of the *UIScrollViewDelegate* **gets called repeatedly while the animation takes place**, letting me update the subview elements according to actual zoom.

The same code on iOS 4.0 does not exibit the same behavior. When I call *zoomToRect:animated:*, the delegates (*scrollViewDidScroll:* and *scrollViewDidZoom*) only get called **once**, which makes my sub elements desinchronized until the animation is finished. In fact, the sub elements immediately jump and then get caught up by the zoom animation until everything is in the correct place. It's as if the animation is not picking up the modifications on the subviews *CALayers*.

I have tried animating manually with animation blocks, but the situation is the same, no progressive callback calls. I have also tried KVO, but it is not clear to me how I would tap into a UIScrollView-managed animation.

Is there a workaround on iOS 4 that would allow me to push the scale value to my subviews as the *UIScrollView* scale is animated?

Answer (score 10):

Brutal but works.

Define some properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *zoomedView;    
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat currentScale;
```

Inform `UIScrollView` which `UIView` is going to be zoomed:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     return self.zoomedView;
}
```

Register for a `CADisplayLink` ticks. It runs Core Animation as well, so it will be kicked on same intervals:

```
self.displayLink  = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkTick)];
[self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Check zoomedView's `presentationLayer` for current values.

```
- (void)displayLinkTick
{
    CALayer *zoomedLayer = self.zoomedView.layer.presentationLayer;
    CGFloat scale = zoomedLayer.transform.m11;

    if (scale != self.currentScale) {
         self.currentScale = scale; // update property

         // the scale has changed!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In IOS 4.0, animations are done by the OS - I assume to make use of GPU based hardware acceleration as much as possible. As a disadvantage of that, it becomes harder to animate a values that is derived from another (animated) value. As in your case, the positions of the subviews that depend on the zoom level of the UIScrollView.
In order to make that happen, you should setup the animation of the subviews to go in parallel with the animation of the zooming. Try something like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                 animations:^{
    theScrollView.zoomScale = zoomScale;
    // layout the subviews here
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

This should set the frame properties of the subviews from within the same animation context, and therefore, they should be animated together by the OS.

See also the answers to this question: [How to make UIScrollView send scrollViewDidScroll messages during animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319906/how-to-make-uiscrollview-send-scrollviewdidscroll-messages-during-animations)

Answer (score -1):

Is it viable to update all the subviews within an animation block (or begin/commitAnimation)?
Something like:

```
[self zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
    animations:^ {
        // change your subviews
    }
];
```

Comment: I have tried this approach, but the problem is that I need to access the current value of the zoomlevel while the zoomming animation is ran, which is not available.

Comment: Could you setup a timer that fires up several times while the zoom animation is going on and make your calculations there?

Answer (score -1):

Register for KVO of the `zoomScale` property of the `UIScrollView` after you call `zoomToRect:animated:`.

```
[scrollView addObserver:self
            forKeyPath:@"zoomScale"
               options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                        NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                context:NULL];
```

Then, implement this method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
              ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"zoomScale"]) {
    // use the new zoomScale value stored
    // in the NSKeyValueChangeNewKey change
    // dictionary key  to resize your subviews
    }
    // be sure to call the super implementation
    // if the superclass implements it
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                ofObject:object
                 change:change
                 context:context];
}
```

Check out the KVO [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Comment: Bumping a really old answer, but I can't seem to get this to work at all.  I register myself as an observer of scrollView for the key path of @"zoomScale", but  observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: never gets called.

Comment: Adam Mika, why don't you use the scrollViewDidZoom from the UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html (its iOS 3.2+ though)

Comment: It's been a long time, but I need to downvote this because it does not work. The observeValueForKeyPath is never called. Not when the zoom ends nor while the zoom occurs.

Comment: does not work here either - but i would need it as `scrollViewDidZoom` does not get called during an animation.