# UITableViewController scrollViewDidScroll: not called during cell removal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a tableView whose content is smaller than the screen, so its not scrolling.

I'm reloading one of the sections when changing to editing mode, which causes the tableView to add rows.

When I now scroll down and then deactivate the editing mode, the tableView removes the redundant cells again and scrolls to top.

During this scroll operation I'm not getting any scrollView delegate calls.
For details, please check my implementation: [GISTViewController.m](https://gist.github.com/julian-weinert/afe440f1e4f4fd5d5fb6)

Comment: I'm assuming you have tableView.delegate set to the view controller?

Comment: It's a subclass of `UITableViewController`, so no need for that. Nevertheless, while dragging it gets called, so its not a general issue with that method

Comment: BLAGH! I a similar issue. This was a problem that crept up with me in iOS 9 and isn't replicated in iOS 8. A subclass of UITableViewController and an override of scrollViewDidScroll is never called, meanwhile, other events such as scrollViewWillBeginDragging are called just fine. I also attempted to reset the delegate, but no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after reading your question a few times, it looks like our issues aren't the same.

I believe your issue is because scrollViewDidScroll: is not called during some animations. You should see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648168/scrollviewdidscroll-on-uitableviewrowanimation), though unaccepted (maybe because they imply user interaction is the only way to trigger it), it also contains a path to [this answer about getting scrolling events during automated animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319906/how-to-make-uiscrollview-send-scrollviewdidscroll-messages-during-animations?lq=1) which may be of help.